# Will the usage of Exo-Skeleton Gear actually weaken the human body over time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, soft-question, biophysics, soft-matter

As we all know, Exo Skeletons as they exist now are just a series of Force multiplying apparatuses working together, also the human body changes to accommodate environment specific factors in order to ensure survival, for instance we all know people who live at high altitudes where the air is thinner naturally grow bigger lungs to ensure that their body gets a fair amount of oxygen it needs to survive, in view of this, I think the usage of exo-skeleton suits will eventually make the user weaker? Your thoughts please.

Comment: My thoughts are that this isn't a question about physics.

Comment: Kindly look up the definition of the tags [soft-question] and [soft-matter], I posted this question in physical fitness but looking at this question from the angle of the effects of the use of Exo-Skeleton Suits on the human body, I believe it holds some relevance with respect to Physics

Comment: This question is , can't say a off-topic , but meant for Biology Stack Exchange and can anyone please tell what physics is lying here??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily about biology.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_exoskeleton, if this is not physics related then I dont know what is...

Comment: @ClementMark-Aaba You're asking if humans will biologically adapt to exoskeletons such that they become weaker than they are now. This is an evolutionary biology question. Also people that live at high altitudes don't grow bigger lungs, they develop more alveoli in their lungs if they grow up at high altitudes. Also, [tag:soft-matter] is not applicable here as this is not about composite materials or objects at characteristic energy scales